# How to pretty print a nested composite object structure conforming to CustomDebugStringConvertible

Tags: swift, foundation, protocol-oriented

I am trying to pretty-print (with indentation for child objects) a composite object structure where the parent and each of the child objects confirm to the CustomDebugStringConvertible protocol.

My code so far is:
import Foundation

```
class StringUtils {
    static func appendIfValuePresent(key: String, value: AnyHashable?, toArray array: inout [String], separator: String = ": ") {
        if let value = value {
            array.append("\(key)\(separator)\(value)")
        }
    }
}

class Address: CustomDebugStringConvertible {
    var city: String? = "B'lore"
    var country: String? = "India"
    var pincode: String? = nil

    var debugDescription: String {
        var components = [String]()
        StringUtils.appendIfValuePresent(key: "city", value: city, toArray: &components)
        StringUtils.appendIfValuePresent(key: "country", value: country, toArray: &components)
        StringUtils.appendIfValuePresent(key: "pincode", value: pincode, toArray: &components)
        let debugStr = components.joined(separator: "\n")
        return debugStr
    }
}

class Contact: CustomDebugStringConvertible {
    var phNum: String? = "111-222-33"
    var email: String? = "ron@example.com"
    var address: Address? = Address()

    var debugDescription: String {
        var components = [String]()
        StringUtils.appendIfValuePresent(key: "phNum", value: phNum, toArray: &components)
        StringUtils.appendIfValuePresent(key: "email", value: email, toArray: &components)
        StringUtils.appendIfValuePresent(key: "address", value: address?.debugDescription, toArray: &components, separator: ":\n")
        let debugStr = components.joined(separator: "\n")
        return debugStr
    }
}

class Student: CustomDebugStringConvertible {
    var name = "ron"
    var contact: Contact? = Contact()
    var debugDescription: String {
        var components = [String]()
        StringUtils.appendIfValuePresent(key: "name", value: name, toArray: &components)
        StringUtils.appendIfValuePresent(key: "contact", value: contact?.debugDescription, toArray: &components, separator: ":\n")
        let debugStr = components.joined(separator: "\n")
        return debugStr
    }
}

let student = Student()

print(student)
```

The output of the above code snippet is:

```
// Actual output
/*
 name: ron
 contact:
 phNum: 111-222-33
 email: ron@example.com
 address:
 city: B'lore
 country: India
*/
```

However, I would like to print like this:

```
// Expected output
/*
 name: ron
 contact:
    phNum: 111-222-33
    email: ron@example.com
    address:
        city: B'lore
        country: India
*/
```

What is the best way to achieve this, retaining the generic structure of the code?

Answer (score 0):

I could devise a solution to my problem and posted a solution here: https://gist.github.com/raunakp/16155d19d005939f1297b7c6cb6f890c

import Foundation

```
class StringUtils {
    static func appendIfValuePresent(key: String, value: AnyHashable?, toArray array: inout [String], separator: String = ": ") {
        if let value = value {
            array.append("\(key)\(separator)\(value)")
        }
    }
}

struct PrettyPrintableComponent {
    var indentationLevel = 0
    var indentationSeparator = "\t"
    var lineSeparator = "\n"
}

protocol HasPrettyPrintableComponent {
    var prettyPrintableComponent: PrettyPrintableComponent { get set }
}

protocol PrettyDebugPrintable: HasPrettyPrintableComponent, CustomDebugStringConvertible { }

extension PrettyDebugPrintable {
    var indentationLevel: Int {
        get { return prettyPrintableComponent.indentationLevel }
        set { prettyPrintableComponent.indentationLevel = newValue }
    }
    var indentationSeparator: String {
        get { return prettyPrintableComponent.indentationSeparator }
        set { prettyPrintableComponent.indentationSeparator = newValue }
    }
    var lineSeparator: String {
        get { return prettyPrintableComponent.lineSeparator }
        set { prettyPrintableComponent.lineSeparator = newValue }
    }
}

class Address: PrettyDebugPrintable {
    var city: String? = "B'lore"
    var country: String? = "India"
    var pincode: String? = nil

    var prettyPrintableComponent = PrettyPrintableComponent()

    var debugDescription: String {
        var components = [String]()
        StringUtils.appendIfValuePresent(key: "city", value: city, toArray: &components)
        StringUtils.appendIfValuePresent(key: "country", value: country, toArray: &components)
        StringUtils.appendIfValuePresent(key: "pincode", value: pincode, toArray: &components)
        let indentationSeparator = String.init(repeating: prettyPrintableComponent.indentationSeparator, count: prettyPrintableComponent.indentationLevel)
        let debugStr = indentationSeparator + components.joined(separator: prettyPrintableComponent.lineSeparator + indentationSeparator)
        return debugStr
    }
}

class Contact: PrettyDebugPrintable {
    var phNum: String? = "111-222-33"
    var email: String? = "ron@example.com"
    var address: Address? = Address()

    var prettyPrintableComponent = PrettyPrintableComponent()

    var debugDescription: String {
        var components = [String]()
        StringUtils.appendIfValuePresent(key: "phNum", value: phNum, toArray: &components)
        StringUtils.appendIfValuePresent(key: "email", value: email, toArray: &components)
        address?.prettyPrintableComponent.indentationLevel = self.prettyPrintableComponent.indentationLevel + 1
        StringUtils.appendIfValuePresent(key: "address", value: address?.debugDescription, toArray: &components, separator: ":\n")
        let indentationSeparator = String.init(repeating: prettyPrintableComponent.indentationSeparator, count: prettyPrintableComponent.indentationLevel)
        let debugStr = indentationSeparator + components.joined(separator: prettyPrintableComponent.lineSeparator + indentationSeparator)
        return debugStr
    }
}

class Student: PrettyDebugPrintable {
    var name = "ron"
    var contact: Contact? = Contact()

    var prettyPrintableComponent = PrettyPrintableComponent()

    var debugDescription: String {
        var components = [String]()
        StringUtils.appendIfValuePresent(key: "name", value: name, toArray: &components)
        contact?.prettyPrintableComponent.indentationLevel = self.prettyPrintableComponent.indentationLevel + 1
        StringUtils.appendIfValuePresent(key: "contact", value: contact?.debugDescription, toArray: &components, separator: ":\n")
        let indentationSeparator = String.init(repeating: prettyPrintableComponent.indentationSeparator, count: prettyPrintableComponent.indentationLevel)
        let debugStr = indentationSeparator + components.joined(separator: prettyPrintableComponent.lineSeparator + indentationSeparator)
        return debugStr
    }
}

let student = Student()

print(student)

// output
/*
name: ron
contact:
    phNum: 111-222-33
    email: ron@example.com
    address:
        city: B'lore
        country: India
*/
```

Comment: Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline. – From [answer].